# horizontal bar drag between stacked divs using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, draggable

So I have two divs above and below each other. The one on top is the content area and the one below is a notes section about the content. I'd like to put an invisible bar in between the two divs where I can drag the height of the two divs. If possible I'd also like to snap to the top or bottom.

I'll attach an example of the current look but the design can change as long as the classes stay the same in the html. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

```
jsfiddle.net/jv4edcc4/
```

Comment: @AndrewEvt here's the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jv4edcc4/)

Comment: `drag the height of the two divs` what does this means?

Comment: @AndrewEvt I want to be able to use a bar in between the two divs that basically controls the height of the notes section. I'd like the main content to be the biggest area but people can use the bar to make the notes section bigger or hide it if they want

Comment: @AndrewEvt here's an example I found but would like it to basically be horizontal instead of this vertical example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bek9L/3020/)

Comment: In fact, jsfiddle does exactly what I'm looking for. The bar in between the HTML and jquery is what I'm looking to achieve in mine. That bar you can drag to adjust what section you want to be bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this - code is simple, you can check how it works here - http://jsfiddle.net/Bek9L/3142/

HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix">
<div id="sidebar">
    <span id="position"></span>
    sidebar
    <div id="dragbar"></div>
</div>
<div id="main">
    main
</div>
</div>
<div id="console"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body,html{width:100%;height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}
.clearfix {
    height: 100%;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
#main{
   background-color: BurlyWood;
   height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
#sidebar{
   background-color: IndianRed;
   width:100%;
   height:50%;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   position: relative;
}

#dragbar{
   background-color:black;
   height:10px;
   width: 100%;
   cursor: row-resize;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#ghostbar{
    width: 100%;
    height:5px;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    position:absolute;
    cursor: col-resize;
    z-index:999
}
```

and JS (uses jQuery):

```
var i = 0;
var dragging = false;
   $('#dragbar').mousedown(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       dragging = true;
       var main = $('#main');
       var ghostbar = $('<div>',
                        {id:'ghostbar',
                         css: {
                                width: main.outerWidth(),
                                top: main.offset().top,
                                left: main.offset().left
                               }
                        }).appendTo('body');

        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
          ghostbar.css("top",e.pageY+2);
       });

    });

   $(document).mouseup(function(e){
       if (dragging) 
       {
           var percentage = (e.pageY / window.innerHeight) * 100;
           var mainPercentage = 100-percentage;

           //$('#console').text("side:" + percentage + " main:" + mainPercentage);

           $('#sidebar').css("height",percentage + "%");
           $('#main').css("height",mainPercentage + "%");
           $('#ghostbar').remove();
           $(document).unbind('mousemove');
           dragging = false;
       }
    });
```

Comment: doesn't drag in example

Comment: try now, forget to update... http://jsfiddle.net/Bek9L/3142/

Comment: Boom that's it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your welcome! Have a nice day) 
pls set +1 for my comment :)